# Which is better?　私は買いましょうか？ or 私が買いましょうか？

Tags: grammar, particles

I am trying to say: "Shall I buy it?"
Which would be better?

私は買いましょうか？ or 私が買いましょうか？

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/9749

Comment: It depends on context by the way, so there isn't really a definite answer.

Comment: Yes, context is very important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of answering which is better, I would like to write some opinion.
If in the situation here,

> Shall I buy it?

"**I**" is not that important
(the person you are talking to, knows it is about "**you buy or not**", not "who to buy it"), I suggest 買いましょうか{かいましょうか} / 買おうか{かおうか} / 買っちゃうか{かっちゃうか} ... which means you wish to have some feedback / you are considering buy or not youself (but saying.. hah)

Apart from "**shall I buy it**", you are actually asking the difference between は and が. Let's keep discussing if you still have problems :)

一緒に頑張りましょう
(look here, you don't have to say 私たちが{わたしたちが}一緒に{いっしょに}頑張りましょう{がんばりましょう})

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "Shall I buy it?" in the sense of **offering to buy something** (i.e. "Do you want me to buy it?" or "Shall I be the one to buy it?") then 私が買いましょうか？ is best.

If "Shall I buy it?" is wondering to oneself "Hmm... shall I buy it?" then neither. That would need a completely different phrase to the two offered in the OP.

Comment: I like this answer, but the way it's arranged is a bit confusing.

Comment: @istrasci Thanks, I tried to arrange it a bit more clearly. I'm trying to make it clear which sense of "Shall I buy it?" it is that "私が買いましょうか？" would be a valid phrasing for.